# Invoke the application to play a music on receiving a push in iOS

Tags: ios, push, apple-push-notifications

I implemented Push notifications in iOS. I want my application to play a music (about 15sec) when I send a push message. I am currently getting the push message, and the music is being played only if the app is in the foreground. 
If the app is in the background, it shows up a notification, and when i tap it, it then plays the music.

But how do I get the functionality of automatically playing the music? I think this can be done because, in iOS, Audio apps can run in the background. So I just want the music to be played when the app goes to background, and it receives a push.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks,
Nithin

Comment: I would immediately uninstall any app that played music on a push. Suppose you had 10 apps installed that did this? You might want to reconsider your design.

Comment: I didn't explain what the app is about. It's a use case if the phone is lost (scream), and this is only for in-house distribution :-) I'm sure you would change your opinion ;) Do you have a solution which can do this?

Comment: You're right; you've found a good use for this. :) Push notifications aren't something I've used in my iPhone programming, so I'm afraid I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are two ways to do this.

**The traditional way** before iOS 7 is to register for audio playing background mode and play a silent sound forever, this will keep your app running in the background for a long time until the user kills it, or it is killed due to low memory.

This way has many drawbacks, the user must launch your app once so that you can start playing the sound and every time the iPhone is shut off, the user need to relaunch your app when he turn on the iPhone.

Also this will consume a lot of battery. 20%-30% a day for an iPhone 5.

**The new way** after iOS 7.0 is to exploit background fetch and remote notification, you can play your sound while performing a background fetch, which has a 30 seconds running time. Also you can trigger a background fetch with a push notification.

This is an article about background fetch and push notification http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html